# Ruby ridk install command throws errors on window 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After successfully installing the latest version of Ruby (version 3.2.0) ie `rubyinstaller-devkit-3.2.0-1-x64.exe`) on Windows 7. When I run the command `ridk install` as requested after Ruby installations on Windows to install comma separated option 1 and 3 below, it throws error below:

```
C:\Users\FRED> ridk install
 _____       _           _____           _        _ _         ___
|  __ \     | |         |_   _|         | |      | | |       |__ \
| |__) |   _| |__  _   _  | |  _ __  ___| |_ __ _| | | ___ _ __ ) |
|  _  / | | | '_ \| | | | | | | '_ \/ __| __/ _` | | |/ _ \ '__/ /
| | \ \ |_| | |_) | |_| |_| |_| | | \__ \ || (_| | | |  __/ | / /_
|_|  \_\__,_|_.__/ \__, |_____|_| |_|___/\__\__,_|_|_|\___|_||____|
                    __/ |           _
                   |___/          _|_ _  __   | | o __  _| _     _
                                   | (_) |    |^| | | |(_|(_)\^/_>

   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update (optional)
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [1,3] 1,3

> sh -lc true
The MSYS2 project is planning to drop active support of Windows 7
and 8.0 sometime during 2022. For more information visit
https://www.msys2.org/docs/windows_support
MSYS2 seems to be properly installed

Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain ...

> pacman -S --needed --noconfirm autoconf autogen automake-wrapper diffutils fil
e gawk grep libtool m4 make patch sed texinfo texinfo-tex wget mingw-w64-ucrt-x8
6_64-binutils mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-
ucrt-x86_64-gcc-libs mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-headers-git mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-lib
mangle-git mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libwinpthread-git mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-make mi
ngw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-tools-git mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-winpthreads-git pkgconf ming
w-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pkgconf
error: mingw32: signature from "Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter
.christoph@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
      1 [main] pacman 2406 dofork: child 2407 - died waiting for dll loading, er
rno 11
error: GPGME error: System error w/o errno
error: mingw64: missing required signature
error: ucrt64: missing required signature
error: clang32: signature from "Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter
.christoph@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
error: clang64: signature from "Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter
.christoph@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
error: msys: signature from "Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 development key) <reiter.ch
ristoph@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signa
ture))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signa
ture))
error: database 'ucrt64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signat
ure))
error: database 'clang32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signa
ture))
error: database 'clang64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signa
ture))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signatur
e))
Install MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain failed
Installation failed: pacman failed

   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update (optional)
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install ruby to be able to run ruby on rails on windows without any issues. You will need to download use **oneclick install options**  at github
[rubyinstaller-3.2.1-1-x64.exe](https://%20https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2.)

Then follow the installation steps.
At the end it will pop up your command prompt requesting you to enter or run **ridk install**.

You will be prompted with options below

1 - MSYS2 base installation

2 - MSYS2 system update (optional)

3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [1,3] 1,3

Just enter 1, 3. and follow installation command.

Once you are done, option 1 which is **1 - MSYS2 base installation** will be install.

Then open another command prompt  and run **ridk install** again. This will install option 3 for you which is  **3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain**. At this junction you are finally done.  You can now go ahead to install Ruby on Rails and everything will be working fine and excellent

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your signatures are outdates. I believe the following might solve your problem:

1. Go to the mysys folder of your ruby installation `C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64`
2. Double click **msys2.exe**
3. Paste (Shift+Insert) the following commands:

```
rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate msys2
```

4. Close mysys2
5. Open Poweshell

```
ridk install
```

6. Install, update and add the development toolchain

Sources:

- [error: xxx: signature from "Christoph Reiter (MSYS2 master key)](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2397)
- [2020-06-29 - new packagers](https://www.msys2.org/news/#2020-06-29-new-packagers)